# Spring Security - XML vs Java Configuration

Tags: spring

I'm just learning Spring Security, and a lot of Spring's documentation appears to use Java-based bean configuration (as opposed to XML.)  Overall, this seems to be the way a lot of their projects are going.  However, portions of their documentation tend to start with Java configuration and then switch to XML config later on.  I found a blurb in one document (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) stating the following:

> Spring Security’s Java Configuration does not expose every property of every object that it configures. This simplifies the configuration for a majority of users. . . . While there are good reasons to not directly expose every property, users may still need more advanced configuration options. To address this Spring Security introduces the concept of an ObjectPostProcessor which can used to modify or replace many of the Object instances created by the Java Configuration.

Can everything that can be done in XML configuration be done with Java config?  Is there a definite direction that the Spring community is taking overall in terms of configuration style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose either java based or xml based configuration.Stick to one, don't mix both.But don't forget to use the annotation based configuration.You just need to annotate spring managed components with @component,@service etc.You don't need to have that bean defenition in xml or java class.

```
 <context:annotation-config/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.package"/>
```

or

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.foo.bar", "org.foo.bar"})
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#jc

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java or XML based. But there is a thing 
Usage of xml based configuration is decreasing in newer versions of Spring. 
Like `@EnableAutoConfiguration` tag... 
With this, web applications doesnt need any XML conf even web.xml